# Apache rotatelogs gives error

Tags: apache-2.2

Recently I have implement apache 2.4.1 in my web server.The problem is the rotate logs seems to be not functioning.Here is the output in the error_log:

```
[core:error] [pid 13060:tid 47015847145408] (2)No such file or directory
```

The command line that i have put in the httpd.conf are such as below:

```
CustomLog "|bin/rotatelogs -l /var/log/logfile.%Y.%m.%d 86400" combined
```

Is there anything wrong here with my setup?For your information I've already tested it in apache 2.2.22 and everythings is perfectly working.

Thanks.

Answer (score 3):

It looks like the user context you are running Apache under does not have rights to create a file in the `/logs` directory. You can validate this quickly by switching to the user that Apache is running under (`sudo su - <username>`) and running

```
touch /logs/testfile
```

Answer (score 1):

Where is the `rotatelogs` binary located on your system?

You don't have a leading slash on your path, which doesn't seem intended - and the file not being found supports that.  You're probably looking for something more along these lines:

```
CustomLog "|/bin/rotatelogs -l /var/log/logfile.%Y.%m.%d 86400" combined
```

Comment: On my CentOS6 box, it's /usr/sbin/rotatelogs, but that's part of the httpd-2.2 package.  It's possible the OP compiled 2.4 himself and stashed it someplace like /usr/local/bin/rotatelogs or /usr/local/sbin.

Comment: I 've already put the full path and tested it.Still not working and gives the same error.Here the command that i have put :

CustomLog "|/usr/local/apache2/bin/rotatelogs /logs/logfile.%Y.%m.%d 86400" combined

Comment: `/logs/logfile`?  Does that path exist?

Comment: Sorry my bad, I have changed into this one:CustomLog "|/usr/local/apache2/bin/rotatelogs /usr/local/apache2/logs/logfile.%Y.%m.%d 86400" and yet it still not working

Answer (score 0):

Use logrotate, which is included by default (if period is ok)
https://fedorahosted.org/logrotate/